# Shell issue for loop in while loop

Tags: shell

I am using while loop to read xyz.txt file and file which contains contents like below:

```
2 - info1 
4 - info2
6 - info3
9 - info4
```

Further I am using if condition to match the count -gt then y value so it will send an email. The problem I am facing every time it matches the if condition it is sending an email which I want once, it should read the file till end and if condition matches store the next line output to a file and then send that file with all information. At present I am receiving number of email.

Hope my question is clear I think I am looking for return function once condition matches it continue reading file till the end and store the info.

```
count=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
cnt=o
while read line
do
if [ "$count" -gt "$x" ]; then ---> This logic is working fine
cnt=$(( $cnt + 1)) --- > This logic is working fine
echo $line > info.txt  -----> In info.txt I want to store info in 1 go which ever matches condition.
export info.txt=$info.txt
${PERL_BIN}/perl $send_mail
fi
done < file.txt
```

Comment: Your code is clearly not the script you're executing — you're missing `do` and `done`.  Your question title mentions `for` and `while` loop; you're only showing a `while` loop.  Please post compilable, runnable code; we can't guess what you're doing wrong if what you post can't run.

Comment: and `count` is probably `cnt`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Totally agree, not sure if I can even call this a pseudo code...

Comment: Actually my code is very long ,I tried to make it simple. My question is if i want to match if condition till EOF before sending email.Count is value which I am taking from input file. cnt=o
while read line
do
if [ "$count" -gt "$x" ]; then ---> This logic is working fine
cnt=$(( $cnt + 1)) --- > This logic is working fine
echo $line > info.txt  -----> In info.txt I want all the info in 1 go which ever matches condition.
export info.txt=$info.txt
${PERL_BIN}/perl $send_mail
fi
done < file.txt

Comment: I recommend that you update your question, rather than trying to reask it as a comment. I'm trying to read it, and struggling much.

Comment: What exactly does `$send_mail` do? What info is it supposed to send? Does it read the info.txt file? Also, I think the `export info.txt` line is bogus. You aren't updating it per loop.

Comment: Jpaugh -- I have updated the code my requirement is just to update info.txt in 1 go and further which i will send by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to send email once, don't put the invocation of Perl which sends mail inside the loop; put it outside the loop (after the end of the loop).  Use append (`>>`) to build the file up piecemeal.

```
count=`echo $line | awk '{print $3}'`
cnt=0   # 0 not o!
while read line
do
    if [ "$count" -gt "$x" ]; then
        cnt=$(($cnt + 1)) 
        echo $line >> info.txt
    fi
done < file.txt

if [ $cnt -gt 0 ]
then
    export info_txt=$info.txt
    ${PERL_BIN}/perl $send_mail
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, Actually my script is too long so I cannot mention done < file.txt in between the script.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  If your script is unreadable, it probably should be broken into smaller scripts.  Incidentally, in most shells, you can't have a variable `info.txt` as you have in the code in the question; I edited the fragment in the answer to use `info_txt` as the exported variable.  I assume that is used by the Perl script.  However, on the whole, it is better to pass the file name as an argument rather than as an environment variable.  Think of environment variables as 'globals'; useful when necessary, but to be avoided when possible.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jonathan . I am using done but at the end of the script .I think as we cannot use multiple done so script will end after this part of script. Actually sending the info.txt is not a problem but the issue is to update the file. Can we use something like return.

Comment: If you wish to end a while loop early, use `break`. It works for `for` loops, too.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've tried to grasp what you want, I think it is this:

First, before the loop, remove any old info.txt file.

```
rm info.txt
```

Then, each time through the loop, append new lines  to it like so:

```
echo $line >> info.txt
```

Notice the double arrows `>>`. This means append, instead of overwrite.

Finally, do the email sending *after* the loop.

Comment: Thanks, could you please confirm when you say "do the email sending after the loop" means if loop or while loop. I have tried after if loop it's not working and my while loops end after 1 page means so many other conditons so I cannot mention done in between.

Comment: Jonathan's solution is the same as mine, but better == fleshed out. If you want to send it only once, you can't do it in a loop that executes more than once. The easiest way is to put it at the end of said while loop---even if it's long, that should still be doable.